# How to display a horizontally scrolling list next to a fixed item?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to display a list of images (equal height) in a horizontally scrolling `div`. This much works, but when I want to have a fixed image - a "cover" image present leftmost inside container the layout gets screwed up.

Below is the CSS and HTML of my work. **If you run the snippet you can see that the list jumps to next line, instead of staying adjacent to "cover" image and scrolling horizantally.** Here is the jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/6x66dLdy/

I can solve it using javascript by setting width of `#list` programmatically, but I want to do it with CSS alone if possible.

```css
#container {
  height: 120px;
  background: #ccccff;
}

#cover {
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  position: relative;
}

#cover img {
  border: 2px solid #cc0000;
}

#list {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  display: inline-block;
}

.item {
  height: 80px;
  margin: 10px 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="cover">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/160x100"/>
    </div>
    <div id="list">
        <div class="item">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/120x80"/>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/60x80"/>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/120x80"/>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/120x80"/>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/120x80"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: why did not #list{width:100px;} in css?

Comment: You have to provide widths for both of your `div`s and the container. Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/6x66dLdy/1/

Comment: @abhitalks: Thanks! please add `calc` as your answer. This is what I was roughly looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happening because you don't have widths specified. You have to provide widths for both of your inner `div`s and also to the container. Giving explicit width to container is advisable because you can then safely assign percent widths to children.

In you use-case, you have to calculate how much width is safer for your `div#cover` and then use the CSS `calc` to calculate the remainder of the width to assign to the list. Also, remember to account for the margins you have.

*Relevant CSS*:

```
width: calc(100% - 240px);
```

*Your fiddle*: ***http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/6x66dLdy/1***

It is always better to specify a proper `box-sizing`. So include this at the top of your CSS:

```
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
```

.

Comment: Can you tell me why `* { box-sizing: border-box; }` is useful in this context? Also for others: if you are writing **less** instead of **css**, use `width: ~"calc(100% - 240px)";` instead.

Comment: This is to ensure cross-browser consistency on box model. `border-box` will ensure that widths are calculated with taking content, padding and border size into account. So you only have to worry about margins and nothing else. More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2Fbox-sizing

Answer (score 1):

Float the `#cover` left and remove the `display: inline-block` from `#list`.

This will allow the cover image and images in the list be any unknown width. Setting a fixed width on the containers like the other answers would not allow this.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6x66dLdy/4/

```
#container {
  height: 120px;
  background: #ccccff;
}

#cover {
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  float: left;
  vertical-align: top;
  position: relative;
}

#cover img {
  border: 2px solid #cc0000;
}

#list {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.item {
  height: 80px;
  margin: 10px 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

test this

http://jsfiddle.net/6x66dLdy/3/

```
#container {
  height: 120px;
  background: #ccccff;
    width:1000px;
}

#cover {
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  position: relative;
    width:200px;
    float:left;
}

#cover img {
  border: 2px solid #cc0000;
}

#list {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  width:600px;
    float:left
}

.item {
  height: 80px;
  margin: 10px 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: I can't fix `#list` width. It won't work for different screen sizes.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question you can specify `min-width:800px;` for the id `#container`
so it does not jump down and stay beside the main picture
here is an example http://jsfiddle.net/6x66dLdy/5/